# HTML/CSS: How to use another font for list-item Bullets

Tags: html, css, formatting, listitem

This question relates to styling of List-Items (< li >)in HTML and CSS
I am having several lists that are ordered with numbers and characters like the following example.

```
<h2>Regulations of use:</h2>
<ol>
<li>Riding no-handed is strictly forbidden.</li>
<li>It is forbidden to modify the rented bike in any way.</li>
<li>In the case of unauthorized use we are entitled, at any time, to prohibit the further use of the bike.</li>
</ol>
```

which should look like:

**Regulations of use:**

1. Riding no-handed is strictly forbidden.
2. It is forbidden to modify the rented bike in any way.
3. In the case of unauthorized use we are entitled, at any time, to
   prohibit the further use of the bike.

But I want to have the numbers in another font and bold. How can this be done?
Is there a selector for the bullets? (Couldn't find one yet). If I do some css like:

```
li{font-weight:bold;}
```

The whole item is bold - which is unwanted.
I even tried

```
ol{font-weight:bold;}
```

which works only for text within the 
`<ol>... </ol>` if it is NOT within a `<li>...</li>`

Actually I hoped there was something like

```
li:bullet{font-weight:bold;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Jv694/2/)**

css

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    counter-reset: li; /* resetting the counter count */
}
li:before {
    content: counter(li); /* if you want numbers a bullet or you can add your custom bullet */
    counter-increment: li; /* if you have counter li then specify its increment */
    color: red; /* it gives you all the freedom to do anything with the bullets just like the any tag */
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background: #aaa;
}

/* to make things appear same as using <ol> and word-break inline with the start word when screen size is small */
li { 
    padding-left: 2em; 
    text-indent: -2em;
}
```

---

If you want alphabets in counter increment **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Jv694/3/)**

counter increment in alphabets css

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    counter-reset: listStyle;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(listStyle, lower-alpha);
    counter-increment: listStyle;
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's (almost) what I have been looking for.
Is there a way to do this with counters like a,b,c,d,e...

Comment: Great Answer THANKS A LOT! That was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry, I can not rate your answer, because I am too young to vote up... (-;

Comment: You can accept this answer. Its my pleasure to help you...:)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ol>
  <li><span>Text</span></li>
  <li><span>More text</span></li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol{
  font-weight:bold;
}
li span { 
  font-weight: normal; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works indeed. But you are formatting the text and not the number. I am still interested if there is another way to format the number only.